# Redmine, publish with basic authentication behind Microsoft TMG

Tags: basic-authentication, redmine

I've just installed Redmine on Windows 2008 R2 through the setup realized by Bitnami.
All works fine. Also SSL is working excellent.
Since today Redmine is in my DMZ, and I reach it directly, from internal network.
I arrive on login page and go.
Now I've published it on public IP with Microsoft TMG.
On TMG I use a listener that require authentication through radius.
TMG permits to pass credential to the web application by some different way, one is basic auth, one is NTLM....
I've found a redmine plugin that permit to use basic auth in redmine, so at login I don't see the redmine page but the classic http popup for credentials.
In this situation, like other published web application, TMG is configured to pass credentials on http basic auth but only redmine fails. 
TMG pass credentials and these are refused by redmine, so TMG propose again credentials request.

Does anyone has a solution? 
It could be a problem in the basic auth plugin, but it's the only one I've founded.

Thanks,
Mirko